# define Picked Files from File picker as Listview datasource in windows 8

Tags: javascript, listview, windows-8, winjs

I am trying to Set files picked using filepiker as List view datasource. 
In Windows 8 using Javascript.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="smallListIconTextTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="smallListIconTextItem">
        <img src="#" class="smallListIconTextItem-Image" data-win-bind="src: picture" />
        <div class="smallListIconTextItem-Detail">
            <h3 data-win-bind="innerText: title"></h3>
            <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: text"></h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="listView_Id" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{
                    itemDataSource: FileData.itemList.dataSource,
                    itemTemplate: select('#smallListIconTextTemplate'),}">
```

**JS:**

```
var dataArray = new Array();
var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();                
openPicker.viewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.list;                
openPicker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll([".epub"]);          
var file;
openPicker.pickMultipleFilesAsync().then(function (files) 
{        
    if (files.size > 0) 
    {            
        for (var i = 0; i < files.size; i++) 
        {         
       dataArray.push({                    
            title: files[i].displayName,                    
            text: "Author",                    
            picture: "/images/BookImage.jpg"                
        });                
            var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(dataArray);                
            var publicMembers = 
            {                    
                itemList: dataList                
            };                
            WinJS.Namespace.define("FileData", publicMembers);
```

I have array with file data. But unable to get in ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a binding issue in the code. FileData.itemList is not initialized at the time of page ui initialization. Right way to do that will be to have a view model observable class with `itemList` member and bind it to the DOM. [Data Binding topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758311.aspx) might help.

otherwise putting this should make it work. You may have to fix up your template to get the display right.

```
listView_Id.winControl.itemDataSource = dataList.dataSource;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is the code[http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6f85d8e6-de9f-4a9f-b6e2-16aee8e3375e/define-picked-files-from-file-picker-as-listview-datasource?forum=winappswithhtml5#48eacad2-3aaa-4afd-9208-7813eb5db11b ] I changed as per suggestion. You can look at that for any changes.